# How to aggregate table by conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a table sorted by keys and time, then added an indicator:

| Key | Time | Value | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:00 | 10.0 | Y |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:15 | 20.0 | Y |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:30 | 30.0 | N |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:45 | 10.0 | Y |
| A | 2021-01-01 01:00 | 10.0 | Y |
| A | 2021-01-01 01:15 | 5.0 | Y |
| B | 2021-01-01 00:00 | 10.0 | Y |
| B | 2021-01-01 00:15 | 10.0 | Y |
| B | 2021-01-01 00:30 | 0.0 | N |
| B | 2021-01-01 00:45 | -30.0 | N |
| C | 2021-01-01 00:00 | 10.0 | Y |
| C | 2021-01-01 00:15 | 70.0 | N |
| C | 2021-01-01 00:30 | 10.0 | Y |
| C | 2021-01-01 00:45 | 25.0 | Y |
| C | 2021-01-01 01:00 | 5.0 | Y |

I would like to add an index with number, skipping the "N".
The index starts from 1 within the same key if the indicator is consecutive equals "Y", resulting:

| Key | Time | Value | Indicator | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:00 | 10.0 | Y | 1 |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:15 | 20.0 | Y | 1 |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:30 | 30.0 | N |  |
| A | 2021-01-01 00:45 | 10.0 | Y | 2 |
| A | 2021-01-01 01:00 | 10.0 | Y | 2 |
| A | 2021-01-01 01:15 | 5.0 | Y | 2 |
| B | 2021-01-01 00:00 | 10.0 | Y | 1 |
| B | 2021-01-01 00:15 | 10.0 | Y | 1 |
| B | 2021-01-01 00:30 | 0.0 | N |  |
| B | 2021-01-01 00:45 | -30.0 | N |  |
| C | 2021-01-01 00:00 | 10.0 | Y | 1 |
| C | 2021-01-01 00:15 | 70.0 | N |  |
| C | 2021-01-01 00:30 | 10.0 | Y | 2 |
| C | 2021-01-01 00:45 | 25.0 | Y | 2 |
| C | 2021-01-01 01:00 | 5.0 | Y | 2 |

How can I have this result?
Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to python so I have no idea how to add a numeric column..

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
mask = df['Indicator'].eq('Y')
mask2 = mask.groupby(df['Key']).shift(fill_value=False)

df['Index'] = ((mask & ~mask2))
               .groupby(df['Key'])
               .cumsum()
               .where(mask)
               .convert_dtypes()
               )
```

Output:

```
   Key              Time  Value Indicator  Index
0    A  2021-01-01 00:00   10.0         Y      1
1    A  2021-01-01 00:15   20.0         Y      1
2    A  2021-01-01 00:30   30.0         N   <NA>
3    A  2021-01-01 00:45   10.0         Y      2
4    A  2021-01-01 01:00   10.0         Y      2
5    A  2021-01-01 01:15    5.0         Y      2
6    B  2021-01-01 00:00   10.0         Y      1
7    B  2021-01-01 00:15   10.0         Y      1
8    B  2021-01-01 00:30    0.0         N   <NA>
9    B  2021-01-01 00:45  -30.0         N   <NA>
10   C  2021-01-01 00:00   10.0         Y      1
11   C  2021-01-01 00:15   70.0         N   <NA>
12   C  2021-01-01 00:30   10.0         Y      2
13   C  2021-01-01 00:45   25.0         Y      2
14   C  2021-01-01 01:00    5.0         Y      2
```